# Cant send GET requests to my router

Tags: get, network-programming, router

So when I try to send a get request, via postman, to my router `asus.router.com` I get the following respons

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <script>top.location.href='/Main_Login.asp?error_status=1&page=index.asp&lock_time=0';</script>
    </HEAD>
</HTML>
```

And when I try to send one directly to my IP address, I get the same. And I dont understand why.

Also, I can reach the website with no problem if I type it in a browser.

I dont know all that much about requests, just the basics that I learned in CS50. So sorry if I am unclear.

Comment: This is most likely down to user agent spoofing. If you're on mac can you try in Paw, add the user-agent header and start typing in the value you will see the auto complete with some common ones. Also set the `accept` header to `text/html`

Comment: @matthauswoolard I am on windows 10. I set another header as accept to text/html. Still didnt work though!